# Make a link with .png executing a php

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, png

I made a PHP script, to generate an image,
I can already embed the image by using `<img src="imageGenerator.php">`,
but now I want to embed the image in forums, but these only support links
ending with `.png`.

Can anyone give me a tip on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: A simple rewrite rule on the server, to direct '/looks-like-a-regular-image.png' to '/some-nefarious-script.php'

Comment: I would rather suggest that the PHP script builds actual image data and returns *that* instead of a .php file. Much safer than including some random script via a rewrite-rule that isn't always fail-proof.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it myself by using this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signature.png$ /signature.php
```

Comment: awesome, I too added an handler in IIS linking *.png with FastCGI